# Cross-project event

Tags: c#, events

I have 2 projects acting as a webserver and a game server. The game server has the webserver as a dependency so I can access its files in the code and I then want to subscribe to an event in the web server.

I have a Discord bot sending information to the webserver that in turn needs to send data to the game server. But as I can't access the game servers file from the webserver I created a static event in the webserver that the game server, in turn, subscribes to. But the event is always null, no matter what I do. Is it even possible to subscribe to an event cross-project like this?

Here is the event:

```
public static event EventHandler<CommandEventArgs> RecievedCommand = delegate{};
```

Here is the invoking method:

```
public static void InvokeEvent(string exector, string command, string channel)
{
    if (!ulong.TryParse(exector, out var user))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a user");
        return;
    }

    if (!ulong.TryParse(channel, out var from))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("not a channel");
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Full invoke");
    CommandEventArgs cmd = new CommandEventArgs();
    cmd.Channel = channel;
    cmd.Command = command;
    cmd.Executor = exector;
    RecievedCommand.Invoke(typeof(BotBridge), cmd);
}
```

Here you can see how I invoke it:

```
if (query["execute"] != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invoking");
    BotBridge.InvokeEvent(query["user"], query["command"], query["channel"]);
    Write(context, "Success!", false);
    return;
}
```

And here is a picture from the game server where I subscribe to the event. The event is registered in the creation of this class so I know for sure the code reaches that part:

```
BotBridge.RecievedCommand += HandleBotCommand;
}

public void HandleBotCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
```

The webserver reaches Console.Writeline("Full invoke") in the invoking method but nothing else happens after that. Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post your code as formatted text, not as images. [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8967612).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I'll change it, thanks

Comment: If the game server and the we server are 2 different processes you have to use a different communication mechanism, a service bus, an internal grpc server...

Comment: @dariogriffo Damn. Would've hoped that I could avoid that.

Comment: [AMQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) as heavy artillery or [Named Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication) for interprocess communication may help.

Answer (score 0):

#### It's not possible to subscribe to an event from a separate process via a project reference.

Even though your game server is referring the "correct web server code/project", it's not pointing to the correct instance.

Here's what's happening:
Your game server code is subscribing to an event from the web server assembly, but in its own process. It's not subscribing to the actually deployed web server.

[image]

- In red: what you were expecting.
- In green: what is actually happening.

For your situation, you would need another communication mechanism such as HTTP, TCP, etc.